# Testing tableview.reloadData()

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uitableview, mocking, xctest

while using a MockTableView this code still not calling reloadData() from the mock,
please i wanna know what is wrong here.

following this book: Test-Driven IOS Development with Swift 4 - Third Edition

page 164, i was as an exercise

[full code repo - on github](https://github.com/ahmed-ibrahim-salim/ToDo-Using-TDD)

**ItemListViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ItemListViewController: UIViewController, ItemManagerSettable {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var dataProvider: (UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate &
                                 ItemManagerSettable)!
    var itemManager: ItemManager?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        itemManager = ItemManager()
        dataProvider.itemManager = itemManager
        tableView.dataSource = dataProvider
        tableView.delegate = dataProvider
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let nextViewController =
            storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
                withIdentifier: "InputViewController")
            as? InputViewController {
            nextViewController.itemManager = itemManager
            
            present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**ItemListViewControllerTest.swift**

```
import XCTest

 @testable import ToDo

 class ItemListViewControllerTest: XCTestCase {

    var sut: ItemListViewController!
    var addButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var action: Selector!
    
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
         "ItemListViewController")
        sut = vc as? ItemListViewController
        addButton = sut.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
        action = addButton.action
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = sut
        
        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
        
    }
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {}

    func testItemListVC_ReloadTableViewWhenAddNewTodoItem() {
        
        let mockTableView = MocktableView()
        sut.tableView = mockTableView
        
        guard let addButton = sut.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem else{
            XCTFail()
            return
        }
        
        guard let action = addButton.action else{
            XCTFail()
            return
        }
        sut.performSelector(onMainThread: action, with: addButton, waitUntilDone: true)
        
        guard let inputViewController = sut.presentedViewController as? 
         InputViewController else{
            XCTFail()
            return
        }
        inputViewController.titleTextField.text = "Test Title"
        inputViewController.save()

        XCTAssertTrue(mockTableView.calledReloadData)
    }
} 

extension ItemListViewControllerTest{
    
    class MocktableView: UITableView{
        
        var calledReloadData: Bool = false
        
        override func reloadData() {
            calledReloadData = true
            super.reloadData()

        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inject a `MockTableview` Then you call `loadViewIfNeeded()`. But because this view controller is storyboard-based and the table view is an outlet, the actual table view is loaded at this time. This replaces your `MockTableview`.

One solution is:

1. Call `loadViewIfNeeded()` first
2. Inject the `MockTableview` to replace the actual table view
3. Call `viewDidLoad()` directly. Even though `loadViewIfNeeded()` already called it, we need to repeat it now that we have a different tableview in place.

Another possible solution:

- Avoid `MockTableview` completely. Continue to use a real table view. You can test whether it reloads data by checking whether the number of rows matches the changed data.

Yet another solution:

- Avoid storyboards. You can do this with plain XIBs (but these lack table view prototype cells) or programmatically.

By the way, I see all your `tearDownWithError()` implementations are empty. Be sure to tear down everything you set up. Otherwise you will end up with multiple instances of your system under test alive at the same time. I explain there here: https://qualitycoding.org/xctestcase-teardown/

Comment: Avoiding `MockTableView` & checking number of rows was the solution, and thank you for your answer sir.

Comment: Yes, there's no need to provide a fake of something unless the real thing is an "awkward dependency" that makes tests uncontrollable, inconsistent, slow, or have unwanted side effects.